# python relative import: module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

```
|Project
|--m1Folder
|--|--__init__.py
|--|--m1.py
|--m2Folder
|--|--__init__.py
|--|--m3Folder
|--|--|--__init__.py
|--|--|--m3.py
```

`m1Folder` and `m2Folder` are inside of `Project`. `m3Folder` is inside of `m2Folder`. All `m*Folder` contains empty `__init__.py`.

How to import m1.py, from m3.py file?

I tried `from m1Folder import m1 as mo` inside `m3.py` file and gave `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'm1Folder'`. However, `pylint` in `vscode` did not show any error.

`from ...m1Folder import m1 as mo` gives `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: Please first read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3 and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194143/3015186

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing the system path with the `sys` module.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
import m1
```

Comment: Is it possible without `sys.path.insert`? Any direct method?

Comment: @Mr.EU I think that this is the simplest solution. I do not know other.

Comment: @Mr.EU as another question, why you can not use that function?